# Confluent Kafka CLI commands are going to interactive mode for creating producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Confluent Kafka CLI commands are going to interactive mode for creating producer and consumer is there anyway to pass data to command instead of typing in interactive shell...?
I'm looking to run commands for producer, create consumer group, subscribe topic, read consumer records and delete records commands to run them in silent mode passing data to command instead of typing it in interactive shell.

```sh
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic --producer.config producer.properties                                                                                                              [2020-06-10 08:46:34,206] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] delivery.timeout.ms should be equal to or larger than linger.ms + request.timeout.ms. Setting it to 1001000. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
[2020-06-10 08:46:35,049] WARN The configuration 'block.on.buffer.full' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
>"Input to Enter"
```

Comment: The question has several issues. (1) kafka-console-producer is not a confluent kafka cli command, it comes with apache kafka. If you need confluent cli you need ccloud. (2) also there is no such thing as deleting records in kafka. The whole idea is that a kafka topic is immutable...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka commands for API to produce message, create consumer group, subscribe to consumer group and read records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312364/kafka-commands-for-api-to-produce-message-create-consumer-group-subscribe-to-c)

Comment: yes it does, but i'm stuck with one more issue. kafka client version we have in source system is very old version 2.11  and kafka-console-consumer command is not working with --broker list command and had to pass --zookeeper instead, but even then command says missing broker id.? Not sure how to do pass it.?