# Kafka commands for API to produce message, create consumer group, subscribe to consumer group and read records

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm using below commands to produce and create consumer groups, facing issue with consumer group not being created,. Can you please help..?

```sh
kafka-producer-perf-test --topic test-one --throughput 1000 --record-size 50 --num-records 10 --producer-props bootstrap.servers='localhost:9092' --producer.config producer.properties
kafka-consumer-perf-test --consumer.config consumer.properties --bootstrap-servers='localhost:9092'  --topic test-one --messages 1
```

Command is able to produce a message but unable to create a consumer group and subscribe to topic instead produced message is consumed by some other topic.

Answer (score 0):

That command, `kafka-producer-perf-test` is only intended to be a self-contained performance test to run on a cluster.

It seems something like this Kafka quickstart would be a much better starting point for you:

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

There's more details in the link, but in summary:

- To produce messages:

  - kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
- To consume messages:

  - kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning

Comment: thanks, i'm trying to automate this setup using shell problem i'm having is console command is running in interactive mode.. how to pass input data to producer command and exit interactive mode...?

Comment: These shell scripts are mostly for testing and validating.  If you're going to produce and consume data in non-interactive mode, you should write some code in whichever language you prefer (java, python, scala, etc) using the corresponding clients.